# Google Map API - click on link gives more information

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

starting point is example showed on next link:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sidebar/random-markers.html

i added new (second) div panel, and i would like that when end user clicks on one of items showed on left panel, it shows more information about it on new div panel.

so, how can i "read" on which item end user clicked? can i also send post request in background, so it can read data from database (using php)?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i manage to solve it....

answer was simple:

```
$('#sideDetailInfo').html( infoWindow.leftLinkId );
```

tnx anw!